# Everytime I run cluster.fork(), I get a Error: bind EADDRINUSE

Tags: node.js, master-slave

I'm using node.js, and using the cluster module. Everytime I run cluster.fork(), I always get a

```
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
Error: bind EADDRINUSE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
at cb (net.js:1205:33)
at rr (cluster.js:592:14)
at Worker.<anonymous> (cluster.js:563:9)
at process.<anonymous> (cluster.js:692:8)
at process.emit (events.js:129:20)
at handleMessage (child_process.js:324:10)
at Pipe.channel.onread (child_process.js:352:11)
```

I've been googling this, and I have no idea how this is happening because I'm not passing in any port numbers.

Thanks

EDIT: Posting code

```
var setupWorkers = function() {
   if (cluster.isMaster) {
   // Fork workers.
       for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       cluster.fork();
   }

 }
```

and this is a function that is called in the app.js which I run by calling node app.js

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: What node version are you using?

Comment: I am using node v0.12.7

Comment: I made a file called test.js that just contains this `var cluster = require('cluster');

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }` and I still get the same error.

Comment: Are you using the `net` module somewhere in your cluster to set up a server? Show us the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was starting a server more than once with all the threads so the port was bound already

Comment: it would be much better if you post your answer with updated working codes, it will help others too :)

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace you provide indicates that `EADDRINUSE` is coming from the `net` module. `EADDRINUSE` typically means that you are trying to listen on an IP/port combination more than once. So, for example, if this is a clustered web server, perhaps all your workers are trying to bind to port 80 on the same IP address. Without more code, it's impossible to tell what's happening.

The example code you gave in the subsequent comment does not trigger `EADDRINUSE` for me. Instead it errors with `cluster.fork is not a function` because there's no check for `cluster.isMaster` before calling `cluster.fork()`.